# SwiftUI: Setting Picker line height

Tags: layout, swiftui, uipickerview, spacing

For large fonts, the lines in a `Picker` are overlapping. How do I change the `Picker's` line height? (Hint: the `.lineSpacing` modifier doesn't do it.)

**See Also**

This question is similar to that of [Ejaaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503379/swiftui-picker-display), but his is so far unanswered.

**The Problem**

[image: picker view]

**The Code**

The following runnable code yields the above result. I don't really want different-sized lines, I just want the large fonts to fit properly. I have tried inserting `Spacers`, adding `.frame` modifiers here and there, `.lineSpacing`, `padding()` ... maybe just haven't found the right combination?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: self.$selected, label: Text("Letters")) {
            Text("A").font(.system(size: 30))
            Text("B").font(.system(size: 40))
            Text("C").font(.system(size: 50))
            Text("D").font(.system(size: 60))
            Text("E").font(.system(size: 70))
            Text("F").font(.system(size: 80))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You have to wrap `UIPickerView` in a `UIViewRepresentable` and then use:

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat
```

… to change your row height.

## Example

It just shows how to change row height, you still have to extend it for your contents...

```
struct PickerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var data: [[String]]
    @Binding var selections: Int

    // Assign custom coordinator for delegate functions.
    func makeCoordinator() -> PickerView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    // Creates the view object and configures its initial state.
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PickerView>) -> UIPickerView {
        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: .zero)

        picker.dataSource = context.coordinator
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator

        return picker
    }

    // Updates the state of the specified view with new information from SwiftUI.
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIPickerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PickerView>) {
        // for i in 0...(self.selections.count - 1) {
        //     view.selectRow(self.selections[i], inComponent: i, animated: false)
        // }
    }


    // Coordinator acting as the delegate in SwiftUI.
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
        var parent: PickerView

        //init(_:)
        init(_ pickerView: PickerView) {
            self.parent = pickerView
        }
        
        // Set your custom row height here!
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 80
        }

        //numberOfComponents(in:)
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return self.parent.data.count
        }

        //pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return self.parent.data[component].count
        }

        //pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return self.parent.data[component][row]
        }

        //pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            // self.parent.selections[component] = row
        }
    }
}
```

To use it in your SwiftUI view, simply place the custom `PickerView()` in your body.

Comment: Thanks, I have had good results with `UIViewRepresentable`, wrapping things with complicated behavior. But I was hoping there would be a native SwiftUI modifier.

Comment: Since there appears to not (yet?) be a SwiftUI modifier for this, I am calling your response the answer. it builds and runs correctly, thank you.

Comment: @Chris while this works great for height, I don't know why but the width of picker just isn't increasing.