# SwiftUI - Change default Picker item height

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently using SwiftUI's Picker API, and would like to increase the Picker row's height. The reason for this is when text has a bigger font, the items overlap.
**I am trying to avoid using UIPickerView + UIViewRepresentable if possible & would like to achieve this using purely SwiftUI if possible.**

I have tried using `Spacers`, `padding` modifiers and `frame` but no luck as of yet.

I know this feature is already available on watchOS, but are there any alternatives when it comes to iOS? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link/defaultwheelpickeritemheight(_:)

I have attached basic picker code with the aforementioned issue. Thanks in advance.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedNum = 0

    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: self.$selectedNum) {
            Text("1").font(.system(size: 80))
            Text("2").font(.system(size: 80))
            Text("3").font(.system(size: 80))
            Text("4").font(.system(size: 80))
            Text("5").font(.system(size: 80))
            Text("6").font(.system(size: 80))
        }
        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
    }
}
```

This is the result of the code

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Setting Picker line height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625848/swiftui-setting-picker-line-height)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I really want to avoid using UIPickerView + UIViewRepresentable if possible & would like to achieve this using purely SwiftUI if possible @xTwisteDx

Comment: Your only other option is to build a custom picker.

Comment: This post might help: [swiftUI picker( the padding of content in Picker does not work)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77772312/20386264)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}
```