# SwiftUI horizontal wheel picker cell item size

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

I'm currently trying to achieve a horizontal picker view where the user can select its avatar shirt. The rotation and adjustments of the picker works fine but my selected picker view cell size does not resize to the actual image size of my items array. This leads to overlapping of my items. I have tried a lot, but is there a way to fix this or is this a common issue in iOS 16.4?

```
    @ViewBuilder func customAvatarView() -> some View {
        List {
            ForEach(Array(sections.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { sectionIndex, element in
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Picker("\(element)", selection: $currentSelection[sectionIndex], content: {
                        DynamicFetchView(predicate: NSPredicate(format: "userID == %@", Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid), sortDescriptors: []) { (shopItems: FetchedResults<ShopData>) in
                            ForEach(shopItems.filter { $0.category == element }, id: \.self) { shopItem in
                                if let image = UIImage(named: shopItem.image ?? "") {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(uiImage: image)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
                    .clipped()
                    .compositingGroup()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

I tried changing the frame of the picker, the layoutPriority, the contentShape etc..

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be possible with SwiftUI itself. Check out this post for a solution to bridge to a `UIPickerView` using `UIViewRepresentable`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625848/swiftui-setting-picker-line-height/61626231#61626231

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Setting Picker line height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625848/swiftui-setting-picker-line-height)